# Identifying case by groups in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to identify the case by groups that is just bigger that avg plus sd. For example, using species as group and petal.wid as my variable in the iris data.

What's the better way to doit? creating a function?

I made this, but I can not make a relation to to orginal data for identifiying the case.

```
data(iris)
library(plyr)
petal.wid.avg <- ddply(iris, .(Species), function(df)
  return(c(petal.wid.avg=mean(df$Petal.Width), petal.wid.sd=sd(df$Petal.Width)))
)
petal.wid.avg$avgsd <- petal.wid.avg$petal.wid.avg + petal.wid.avg$petal.wid.sd
petal.wid.avg
```

Comment: Your example wasn't reproducible.  I changed it. Now it is.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want exactly.  Can you provide some example output of what you're hoping for?

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways of doing this, but the `ave` function is perhaps the easiest.

```
iris$big <- with(iris, 
  ave(Petal.Width, Species, FUN = function(x) x > mean(x) + sd(x))
)
```

Here's the `plyr` solution:

```
iris <- ddply(
  datasets::iris, 
  .(Species), 
  transform, 
  big = Petal.Width > mean(Petal.Width) + sd(Petal.Width) 
)
```

---

Baed on the comments, here's the rest of the solution.

```
iris <- subset(iris, big)
iris <- ddply(
  iris,
  .(Species),
  transform,
  smallest = Petal.Width == min(Petal.Width)
)
(iris <- subset(iris, smallest))
```

Note that where you have ties (as in this dataset), you won't get a unique "just bigger" row.

Comment: My interpretation is that you have reproduced the code in the question. Now the question is to identify the single element of each species that is *just* larger than a cut-off point (i.e. larger than mean + sd)

Comment: Thank you both for you help, but that's what i'm trying to figure out. The just larger value.